# Need a solution for my project to replace the current .NET Remoting solution

Tags: .net, remoting

I have a project with requirements:

- Clients connect to server through internet (WAN) to get data.
- Server can notify to clients when server has new data.

P/S: Client is a .NET WinForm application. Someone suggest me to use .NET Remoting but it only works well on LAN and it has problem when send event to clients through internet.

Please help me a replace solution. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I wonder that WCF can solve the problem when server want to send event to client through internet. If yes, please send me the article which solves this problem. And the server can send only some clients, not all clients? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is the replacement for .NET Remoting.

See [Beginner's Guide to Windows Communication Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx) to get started.

Comment: But I wonder that WCF can solve the problem when server want to send event to client through internet. If yes, please send me the article which solves this problem.

And the server can send only some clients, not all clients? Thanks.

Comment: WCF supports bidirectional communications. The client can call back to the service, even over the Internet. It's just a matter of using a duplex binding. See "WCF Callbacks; a beginners guide" at http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) allows you to wirte a service which can be connected via HTTP or TCP/IP over the internet or network.

Remoting was a predecessor to WCF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx